# Send row count of a table in Oozie success email

Tags: pyspark, oozie-workflow

I have a Pyspark code which is scheduled to run by Oozie. I need to print the total row count of the output table created by this workflow in the Succes email.

I have set this row count as an environment variable in the pyspark code.

```
row_count = output_table.count()
print(f"Row count of table: {row_count}")
os.environ["ROW_COUNT"] = str(row_count)
```

Here is the action in workflow.xml:

```
<action name="sendSuccessEmail">
           <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
               <to>${successEmailTo}</to>
               <subject>${clusterName}: Workflow suceeded for the date: ${nominal_date}</subject>
               <body>
                Hi Team,

                The workflow completed successfully for the date ${nominal_date}.
                    Workflow details
                    ----------------
                    Cluster Name:   ${clusterName}
                    Nominal time:   ${nominal_date}
                    End time:       ${timestamp()}
                    Row count:      ${env::ROW_COUNT}
                    
                Note: This is a auto generated email, for any further details please contact our DE team.
               </body>
           </email>
           <ok to="end"/>
       <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
```

Can someone review this since I'm unable to achieve the needed. Also can suggest any other ways of doing it.

Comment: You need to share more info like what error you are getting ?

Comment: My workflow fails without any error message